# Ubuntu 16.04 does not recognize my built-in bluetooth adapter

Tags: drivers, kernel, bluetooth, acer, firmware

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my Acer Aspire E5-573-347G, and I have not had any problems until I needed to use bluetooth.

The Unity bluetooth menu does not allows me to use any options, as can be viewed below.

[image: Bluetooth menu]

The `lsusb` command returns this information:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 1bcf:2c81 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1c4f:0002 SiGma Micro Keyboard TRACER Gamma Ivory
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 2188:0ae1  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

After that, I used `rfkill list`:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

[Update 1]
When I use the`hcitool scan` command, the system returns the following message:
`Device is not available: No such device`

[Update 2] 
Output of command `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [11ad:0803]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k
```

Comment: Is your wifi card turned on? Usually it has to be turned on before Bluetooth can be turned on. Then after turning Bluetooth on you have to make your computer visible to pair up devices.

Comment: Yes. My wifi card is turned on and my laptop doesn't have a button do turn on/off the Bluetooth card. The problem is that the system don't recognize my bluetooth adapter.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Question updated.
The outuput is described above.

Answer (score 0):

Start the `terminal` from the dashboard.

type `cd /var/log`

then type `grep -i firmware syslog*`

These commands will search the system log looking for the word `firmware`. Look for any text indicating that it's having trouble loading firmware.

If so, then

type `sudo apt-get update`

then type `sudo apt-get install linux-firmware`

Then **reboot the computer**.

These commands will install a missing firmware file that the bluetooth adapter probably needs. No harm done if it doesn't.

If that all doesn't fix your problem, review this from a Google search that I did:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1532267

It sounds kind of like your problem too.

Keep us posted. Cheers, Al

Comment: Sorry for the late to report what happened. Well, I tried everything you describes, but without success.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and tried all the possible solutions available on different platforms. The only thing I needed to do was turn off the secure boot from the bios.
Worked for me.